# Flex items not aligning side-by-side

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, flexbox

I've the below code. The divs and fonts resizing are working perfectly with me.

I designed it with mobile first in mind, so for small screens, the `widgets` are coming under each other as required.

In big screens, like laptop, 3 widgets should come beside each other. Unfortunately, I'm still getting them under each other, one widget each line.

What I'm missing or a mistake I'm doing here?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5
}
html {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.7vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 4.0vw;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2.8vw;
}
.widget {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.01em 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)!important;
  width: 30vw;
}
.topleft {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .3
}
.bottomright {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: .3
}
/* p {font-size: 2.5vw;}  */

.kpi {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 6vw;
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*       p {font-size: 3.5vw;}  */
  .kpi {
    font-size: 11.5vw;
    line-height: 10.5vw;
  }
  .widget {
    width: 50vw;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /*       p {font-size: 3.5vw;}  */
  .kpi {
    font-size: 20vw;
    line-height: 19vw;
  }
  .widget {
    width: 85vw;
  }
  .topleft {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
  .bottomright {
    font-size: 6vw;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  aside,
  section {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main" .style="{ display: flex; /* or inline-flex */ flex-direction: row;}">
  <div class='widget'>
    <p class='topleft'>SoH</p>
    <p class='kpi'>12345</p>
    <p class='bottomright'>KG</p>
  </div>
  <div class='widget'>
    <p class='topleft'>SoH</p>
    <p class='kpi'>12345</p>
    <p class='bottomright'>KG</p>
  </div>
  <div class='widget'>
    <p class='topleft'>SoH</p>
    <p class='kpi'>12345</p>
    <p class='bottomright'>KG</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors.

This is wrong:

```
<main class="main" .style="{ display: flex; /* or inline-flex */ flex-direction: row;}">
```

It should be:

```
<main class="main" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0n8f5z8s/)

**UPDATE**

use `flex-wrap:wrap` to wrap it properly in rows/columns to make it best displayed in the screen

```
<main class="main" style="display: flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it is coming in single line even in small screens, in small screens should come under each others :(

Comment: That's because you put the flex directive in your `main` element. Instead, put it in a media query. https://jsfiddle.net/0n8f5z8s/1/

Comment: Thanks, it worked by replacing the `flex-direction: row;` by `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: There are several ways to do this. I can think of at least five off-hand, but only you know all the details about the layout objective. Btw, you're not replacing `flex-direction: row` with `flex-wrap: wrap`, you're just adding `flex-wrap: wrap`. The default value for `flex-direction` is already `row`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a period in front of the style tag. That might be why it is not picking up the display:flex, but I would also add flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:centre (or space-around, space-between, whichever you prefer) and align-items:flex-start or centre.

You also might need to add for the media query when you want it to be in a column changing the flex direction to a column.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `flex-wrap:wrap` solved my issue, can I added code to your answer.